# multiple file upload handling with backing bean

Tags: jsf, file-upload

I have a page with a file upload input from tomahawk's components. I want to know if putting 5 upload inputs with a single button those will be sent as part of the form.

And I want also some ideas on how I can make my managed bean to adapt for this multiple file upload.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[PrimeFaces](http://www.primefaces.org/)' upload component manages multi-upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can just simply map each file to different variables in your backing bean. When the user clicks submit button, you can get all your files from these variables at 1 go.